# Is it bad practice if I use one endpoint to monitor another endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, express

I have a web application with various endpoints, and I have to create a dashboard tool to monitor the statuses of those endpoints.

For example, one of my web application endpoint is `base-uri/api/v1/apple/`.

On my dashboard, I need to display whether the server status is up/down at that endpoint. I'm currently writing the backend of my dashboard using Node and Express, and a snippet of it looks like this:

```
app.get('/testAppleEndPoint', function (req, res) {
    fetch('base-uri/api/v1/apple/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(error);
})
```

When I go to my dashboard endpoint `/testAppleEndPoint`, it will use fetch to test whether my web application's end point `base-uri/api/v1/apple/` is working or not.

Is this bad practice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think this question is more suited for Stack Exchange's [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions) site.

Comment: If you do it like this, simply passing through the response, you are essentially setting up a proxy. Why wouldn't you call the other endpoint directly? If both endpoints are located on the same server, then you're not necessarily testing if the server is 'up' since your request might be routed over localhost instead of the internet (depends on configuration and how you issue the request).